# ASP.NET Core API System.InvalidOperationException in localization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, translation

I've been trying to use localization in my webAPI but every time I have this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ITempDataDictionaryFactory' has been registered.

Here's my Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using System.Globalization;
using testeTraducao.Controllers;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using testeTraducao.Localize;
using testeTraducao.Resources;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddLocalization(opt => opt.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
builder.Services.AddControllers();


builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new() { Title = "testeTraducao", Version = "v1" });
});

var app = builder.Build();


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "testeTraducao v1"));
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

var supportedCultures = new[]
{
    new CultureInfo("en-UK"),
    new CultureInfo("pt-BR")
};

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-UK"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
});

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

I saw some people saying to add `builder.Services.AddMvc();` but, still not working, but with a different error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'test' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Traduzido/test.cshtml
/Views/Shared/test.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/test.cshtml
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable`1 originalLocations)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Here's some info:

My folders structure:

[image: Folder structure]

[image: resx file]

Controller:

```
public class TraduzidoController : Controller
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<SharedResources> _localizador;
    public TraduzidoController(IStringLocalizer<SharedResources> localizador)
    {
        _localizador = localizador;
    }
    [HttpGet("/traduz")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_localizador["test"]);
    }
}
```

target framework:
`<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>`

--edit--
After changing to `return Ok(_localizador["test"]);`  still can't get the message:

[image: check the return here]

Comment: Please replace images with code as it's much easier to read and debug

Answer (score 1):

`return View(_localizador["test"]);` means that you are attempting to get a view called `test`, which in this case is localised.

Definitely add `builder.Services.AddMvc();` but then also add in a view file, which is what the errors are detailing:

`The view 'test' was not found`

Create a root `Views` folder, a `Traduzido` folder inside there for your controller's views & finally, add in a `test.cshtml` file to fix the errors.

Comment: i was so distracted that i couldn't see that i was trying to return a view hahaha
but i still cant get the message, so i edited the post

Answer (score 0):

try adding `builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();` to your program.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

An API controller inherits from ControllerBase. This is a controller built without view support

```
//API Controller
public class YourController:ControllerBase
```

An MVC controller inherits from Controller

```
//MVC Controller
public class YourController:Controller
```